# How to fix “Soft 404" in GWT even though the page is ok

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors, soft-404

Why does Google Search Console report that this page is a soft 404, even though it's OK?

https://www.tsikot.com/forums/showthread.php/72558-Mitsubishi-Pajero-Fieldmaster-(Gen-2.5)-continued/page55

Comment: Google does not seem to be particularly bright when it comes to detecting soft 404's. Many have balked at how poor the mechanism is. It comes down to whether certain simple phrases are found on the page, for example, *not found*. No-one can list all the phrases, however, this appears to be what sets off the false alarms.

Comment: Something makes me think that google cannot process mixed-language pages too well.

Comment: There appears to be several resources on that page that are generating 404s - maybe that has something to do with it?